# method overloading in php?

Tags: php, oop, overloading

Sorry if this is a stupid question - I have learnt some java previously and I know that PHP adopts some of its object oriented concepts, I was wondering if it is possible to overload methods in a similar manner to something like the following:

```
public function add($number1, $number2){
        return ($number1 + $number2);
    }

    public function add($number1, $number2, $number3){
        return ($number1 + $number2 +$number3);
    }
```

is this possible in PHP or have I majorly missed something - apologies if stupid in advance just trying to gain a deeper understanding.

Comment: The simple answer: no, PHP does not support method overloading (unless you count `__call`, though that is more of a workaround).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not support overloading of methods/functions, but it does support variable number of arguments via [func_num_args](http://www.php.net/func_num_args) and [func_get_arg](http://www.php.net/func_get_arg)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP there is not a real method overloading as seen in other programming languages like java or c++ but you can use optional parameters in this way

```
 public function add($number1, $number2, $number3 = 0){
     return ($number1 + $number2 + $number3);
 }
```

$number3 is optional with value 0

Or you can pass an **array** of values or just use try **func_get_arg()**

```
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have any kind of pattern matching for function signatures. The best you could do is to emulate it:

```
class A {
  public function a() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    switch (count($args)) {
      case 0:
        $overload = array($this, '_a0');
        break;
      case 1:
        $overload = array($this, '_a1');
        break;
      default:
        // … etc
    }
    return call_user_func_array($overload, $args);
  }
  protected function _a0() { … }
  protected function _a1($arg) { … }
  // …
}
```

But this is probably more trouble than it's worth IRL.

Comment: This is method overriding, not overloading (which is what the op asked for)

Comment: @RainFromHeaven oops, you're completely right. Rewritten.